# Time-to-event analysis when having panel data

Tags: r, survival, panel-data, time-varying-covariate

Right now I'm starting a project where panel (time-stamped) data should be used to predict time-to-event (in this case time until death of certain player). Data consists of ID, multiple time-dependent covariates, multiple categorical covariates, death flag (0 if alive at that point, otherwise 1). For example:

```
+-----+------+------+-------+-----+---------------+-------+
| Id  | Var1 | Var2 | start | end | time_to_event | event |
+-----+------+------+-------+-----+---------------+-------+
| 1   | 6    | 6,3  |     0 |   2 |           440 |     0 |
| 1   | 4,8  | 7,2  |     2 |   4 |           438 |     0 |
| 1   | 5,3  | 7    |     2 |   6 |           436 |     0 |
| ... |      |      |       |     |               |       |
| 1   | 4,2  | 5    |   438 | 440 |             0 |     1 |
| ... |      |      |       |     |               |       |
| 2   | 1,2  | 0,6  |     0 |   2 |            26 |     0 |
| 2   | 16,2 | 1,9  |     2 |   4 |            24 |     0 |
| 2   | 2,3  | 6    |     2 |   6 |            22 |     0 |
| ... |      |      |       |     |               |       |
| 2   | 1,1  | 1    |    24 |  26 |             0 |     1 |
+-----+------+------+-------+-----+---------------+-------+
```

Above is just an example, but primary structure looks like this. Dataset contains a lot of subjects (ID's) with multiple timestamps (different number of timestamps for every player). Did my research about models for this kind of problem but it is still unclear to me where to properly start.
So basically my question is - what's most common method to analyze this kind of data for time-to-event analysis? I'm mainly confused how to implement this dataset with the fact that in contains multiple subjects with different number of timestamps for each of them..
Any kind of help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!